# How to pass Origin to Header in Alamofire Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I want to add "Origin" to Header to url works. I'm using Alamofire but seemly it not support. Anyone have experienced with this, please help me!![image]

Comment: If you have been around for more than a year, you should know by now that that is not how we present code here.

Comment: I'm a beginner, so can you explan help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the header in Alamofire in following way using key/value pair.

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = ["Accept": "application/json",
                            "Origin": "http://domain.foo"
                           ]
```